# Convert an array of objects

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, casting

how can i convert from:

```
object[] myArray
```

to

```
Foo[] myCastArray
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To filter elements by `Foo` type:

```
Foo[] myCastArray = myArray.OfType<Foo>().ToArray();
```

To try to cast each element to `Foo` type:

```
Foo[] myCastArray = myArray.Cast<Foo>().ToArray();
```

*Side note:* Interestingly enough, C# supports a feature (*misfeature?*) called [array covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572(VS.71).aspx). It means if `Derived` is a reference that can be converted to `Base`, you can implicitly cast `Derived[]` to `Base[]` (which might be unsafe in some circumstances, see below). This is true **only for arrays** and not `List<T>` or other stuff. The opposite (array contravariance) is not true, that is, you cannot cast `object[]` to `string[]`.

C# version 4.0 is going to support safe covariance and contravariance for generics too.

Example where array covariance might cause problems:

```
void FillArray(object[] test) {
   test[0] = 0;
}
void Test() {
     FillArray(new string[] { "test" });
}
```

I speculate C# has array covariance because Java had it. It really doesn't fit well in the overall C# style of doing things.